# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I want to store the student info in the same sequence order, how it's coming from the service call. For eg.,

```
{  
    {
        department: "C.Sci",
        students: [
            Amul,
            Ankit,
            Anoop
        ]
    },
    ........
    ........
    {
        department: "M.Sci",
        students: [
            Bosch,
            Peter,
            Vinya
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I'm using NSOrderedSet to achieve this, but my app end up with crash. Also, selected the checkbox "Ordered" in the show data model inspector. Any help?

Comment: can you please share the code that is causing the crash.

Comment: Core Data uses all kinds of wizardry behind the scenes. The intersectsSet: method is apparently what Core Data uses when you add an object to that particular relationship. If you look up NSOrderedSet's intersectsSet: method, you'll find that it expects an NSSet as its parameter -- which apparently it's not getting. And that's all I can tell you without more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOrderedSet` is kinda like an array, (but objects can't be inserted twice), and it is kinda like a set, (but objects have order), and is a subclass of neither.  So if you have a method that wants a `NSSet`, an `NSOrderedSet` is not going to cut it.  You can use the method `set` or `NSOrderedSet` to get a `NSSet`.

```
NSOrderedSet* myOrderedSet = ...
NSSet* mySet = ...
//[mySet intersectsSet:myOrderedSet]; //bad crashes!!
[mySet intersectsSet:myOrderedSet.set]; //good! no crash
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I knew that, my question is app crashing, if I'm using `NSOrderSet`, how to rectify it.

Comment: I'm not using any intersectsSet, I'm just trying to add an object into `NSOrderedSet` relationship object, then the app crash.